# changing data attribute isn't working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change a data attribute, but it never seems to get changed and remains as "TEXT", which is the default.

```
function SuccessGetActorsForGroupCallback(data, el) {
    var str = "";
    jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {
        str += val + '<br />';
    });

    $(el).data('original-title', str);
    Utilities.ApplyTooltips($(el));
}
```

Please help

Comment: The [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method doesn't alter the `data-` HTML attribute; it alters a variable that jQuery stores internally.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. What does Utilities.ApplyTooltips do? What does the markup look like?

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful. How does `data` look like and what does `ApplyTooltips` do?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method doesn't alter the `data-` HTML attribute; it alters a variable that jQuery stores internally.

If you really need/want to alter the `data-` attribute, do so explicitly with the `.attr()` method:

```
$(el).attr('data-original-title', str);
```

***However,*** this won't alter the value returned by `.data`. jQuery will fetch that value from the `data-` HTML attribute *only if* it can't find the value stored internally. If you retrieve `$(el).data('original-title')` again after altering the HTML attribute, you'll find it hasn't changed.

If *this* is a a problem, use the [`.removeData()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeData/) method to delete the internally-stored value. The next time you use `.data()`, jQuery will see that it's missing and retrieve the `data-` HTML attribute.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/LHCUK/

---

HTML:

```
<p id="p" data-title="blah"></p>
```

jQuery:

```
console.log($('#p').data('title')); // returns "blah"

// alter the attribute directly
$('#p').attr('data-title','whooo'); // data-title="whooo"
// test if .data is changed
console.log($('#p').data('title')); // still returns "blah"

// delete the .data() value
$('#p').removeData('title');
// now fetch it again -- it will retrieve the new data- attribute
console.log($('#p').data('title')); // returns "whooo"
```

---

Now, in practice, you shouldn't have to worry about this. Just remember that the `data-` attribute represents the *initial* value of a `.data()` variable and not necessarily the *current* value of that variable, and you'll be fine.

**In summary:** The `.data()` method retrieves a value from the HTML element ***once*** when the document is loaded, and will not do so again as long as the variable is stored internally.

Answer (score 2):

Your code: `$(el).data('original-title', str);`
should be: `$(el).attr('data-original-title', str);`

`.attr();` is used to change attributes if used in key - value pairs.

[Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: that might need to be 'data-original-title'

Comment: I basically put in there, what he specified, I think the point was clear enough tho. However I edited my answer, thanks for the tip!