# Jquery caching data-* attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my HTML page , I have the following div:

`<div id="notification"></div>`

An ajax call add some attribute to that div after receiving successful response.This is what the ajax success does:

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dummy/url",
            data: {Redacted},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#notification').attr({'data-status': data['status'], 'data-message': data['message']});
                $('#notification').click();
                $('#notification').removeAttr("data-status data-message");
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem is the attributes of #notification does not go away after using removeAttr. I mean it removes the attributes from the page, but remains as cached. Thats why **I am getting same data-message on every click though the server returns different data-message**.

For example:

In my first ajax call, server returned:

`{"status":"success","message":"Invitation sent"}`

In this case the #notification triggers and shows me data-message="**Invitation Sent**". But in my second call server returned:

`{"status":"danger","message":"Invitation sending failed"}`

But #notification shows data-message="**Invitation Sent**" again.

Any suggestion for me on this? How can I remove the cached data? Or is there any alternative of what I am doing up there?

Comment: Check the value of `data` inside your `success` callback. Is it being cached? If so, [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880122/901048) may be all you need.

Comment: use `data()` and `removeData()` instead

Comment: If I had to guess, there's an click event listener on `#notification` that grabs the `data-status` and `data-message` data to pass into another function. Why not just skip simulating the click and handling resulting event and instead pass `data.status` and `data.message` directly into the method called by the click listener?

Comment: what @Brian suggests is better way to handle the notifications. You should go with it. And if you can provide some jsbin or jsfiddle for your problem we could provide better solution or explanation to your problem.

Comment: *"But #notification shows data-message="Invitation Sent" again."* Where?

Comment: @Blazemonger , data inside success is not being cached.

Comment: @KevinB the attributes are changing in my div after success call. But it shows the old attributes when triggers.

Comment: @TarekSiddiki How are you testing that?

Comment: @TarekSiddiki my first comment is the correct way to do this, but to completely prevent caching add a timestamp query string to the URL you're calling.

Comment: @Brian the ajax request isn't being cached.

Comment: The difficulty in this question is the misconception that something is being cached. Nothing is being cached, you're using a POST request, and .attr doesn't do any kind of caching. The problem isn't being described very well, and with such little code in the question, it's impossible to figure out what the real problem is. My only guess is that inside the click handler you are triggering you are using .data() to retrieve the attribute value which of course copies the values from teh attribute to an internal data storage *that is from then on completely separated from attributes*.

Comment: If that were the case, simply switching to using .attr across the board would fix it.

Comment: @KevinB [Relevant example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520349/changing-data-attribute-isnt-working/19520429#19520429). If that's the real problem, this question should be considered a duplicate.

Comment: @KevinB to add to what you said - if you change a data-* attribute's value, you need to access it using `attr('data-*')` instead of `data()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using attribute, use `data()`. If you had already used `data()` to read the attribute it is going to be cached as a property of the element.

```
success: function (data) {
    var elementData = {
        status: data['status'],
        message: data['message']
    }

    $('#notification').data(elementData);
    $('#notification').click();
    // not sure why it needs to be removed here
    // if it does use `removeData()

}
```

Comment: You're assuming he's using `.data()` elsewhere in his code to read the value, but he hasn't said so.

Comment: @Blazemonger no , hasn't explicitly said so but if it is this would resolve it

Comment: By default there is no `data-message` and `data-status` attribute in my `#notification` . I am assigning new attr() after receiving success call.

Comment: Need to show more code then that uses the attributes, and a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem would help.