# Changing data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, input

I'm looking for a solution to change a data attribute I've got on a input form. I need to add 30 minutes onto the values within the two data attributes. I assume I would need to do this is some sort of JS - I'm not too experienced, anyone with any ideas of where to start?

Thanks!

```
<div class="input">
<label>Drop off time</label>
<label class="dropoff-time-hour">
<select class="hour" required **data-dropoff-hour="16"**>
</select>
</label>

<label class="dropoff-time-min">
<select class="min" required **data-dropoff-min="35"**>
</select>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing data attribute isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520349/changing-data-attribute-isnt-working)

Comment: @Surreal unfortunately there are no pure JavaScript answers in that question.

Comment: _"I assume I would need to do this is some sort of JS"_ - yes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For changing the `data-dropoff-min` value

`$('select[class="hour"]').attr('data-dropoff-hour', "Your Updated value");`

Replace the string **"Your Updated value"** with your updated value.

In general,
`$(selector).attr('data-attribute', 'updated value');`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you - I will give that a go.